# Should I spray down the shower with a diluted bleach solution after using it?

Tags: shower, mold

I have a tile shower in the basement that is not very well ventilated.  My mother-in-law suggested a spray bottle of 1/2 bleach, 1/2 water, and spraying it around the surfaces of the shower after using it to help prevent mold.

Is mother-in-law always right?  Is this a good idea?

Comment: I use one of those automatic shower cleaner sprayers.  I fill it with everyday use mist from the dollar store.

Comment: I'm not adding another answer, but this seems like way overkill.  Getting a squeegee and drying it off would be effective and not so intrusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be okay. don't ever get any of that bleach onto clothes or towels.
you should get the ventilation sorted, as mold spores will multiply in that area outside the shower. also chlorinated hot water releases chloride gas readily, which is not great to breathe in. i suggest short showers.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about the ventilation.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Bleach in a "poorly ventilated" indoor area is a horrible idea and harmful to the skin and lungs, especially when less toxic alternatives exist

Answer (score 4):

Vinegar works just as well, without all the worries - use 30 percent vinegar to 70 percent water.

Also, make a habit of wiping down the shower with your towel after you dry off. It'll collect all that water, which will then be vented out of the house when you wash & dry it.

Comment: I like the towel idea.  Should of thought of that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If ventilation is limited then try using a dehumidifier in the basement area - you'd be amazed about how much water they can collect.

Comment: I'll keep the dehumidifier in mind.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I made the mistake of just taking a bottle of bleach to my shower after noticing an especially bad amount of mold (college days). I think dilution is definitely a necessity for breathing purposes. I second the concern of not getting any on your clothes and also washing yourself thoroughly after using the bleach. While I didn't get any on my clothes, I did have some on my hands when I went to scratch my back and it ruined one of my favorite black t-shirts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The bleach is diluted, but I'll be sure to use caution, especially around clothing.

Answer (score 2):

We use this product for years. It works like a dream- not only does it slow down mould growth, it disinfects and removed mould while you are looking at it. It is a combination of bleach and other sorts so it will damage clothing too. Also it has an overpowering odour so you need to spray it and get away. You do not need to use this every time just every other time.

[image]

You should maybe also consider and old towel to wipe down the tiles and shower area after usage and take the towel to ventilated area to dry.

Answer (score 1):

Laundry Bleach is a dangerous oxidizer that can burn your skin and lungs and it is actually a very poor solution for mold.  In most cases, the active ingredient (the sodium hypochlorite) quickly evaporates into the air (that you breathe) rather than penetrating your surface.  Bleach usually won't fix the mold because it doesn't stick around long enough or penetrate deep enough to kill the mold.  The water in the bleach feeds the mold. 
I recommend:

1. Reduce the residual moisture in your shower/bath area by wiping the walls down with a soft squeegee or towel after each use - this greatly reduces soap film accumulation and reduces the need to clean the area.
2. Make sure your ceiling vent fan is not full of lint, dust or a bird nests at the discharge point.  If you don't have a vent fan, install one that vents to the exterior (not the attic).
3. Run your vent fan 20-30 minutes past the end of your shower to extract moisture - Install a Leviton or Lutron electronic wall timer in the position that your fan switch occupies.
4. Use more user-friendly cleaners such as white vinegar (this also helps cut the soap film).  Borax and TSP are good anti-microbials to clean with.  In basement corners, a periodic spray with a product such as Concrobium Mold Control every few months (or similar) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I use a diluted bleach solution in my shower (25% bleach/75% water) in a hot/humid area on Oahu, and it keeps the mold away and keeps the shower white and clean looking. It IS ventilated with a window however, so I may have a different experience with someone using it downstairs in a basement, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Mold needs three things, food, moisture, and oxygen. Look at it like a three legged stool, remove one and it will fall. I solved it in my shower room by placing a fan to blow into the shower room for about 1 and 1/2 hours after a shower. It is a cheap box store 20" one set on medium with a timer. No troubles since. The reason it works it removes the moisture. You can also use hydrogen peroxide to kill mold but be careful with it. Use it straight from the bottle (3.5%) and spray on hard surfaces.